# Firebase function for Algolia returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am following the Firebase tutorial on how to implement Algolia with Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

I am currently stuck on the indexing part of the tutorial as I have errors coming from the firebase cloud-functions logs.
**This is the output of the cloud-functions log**
[image]

and this is the code I wrote

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");

const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.key;
const ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY = functions.config().algolia.search_key;

const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'users';
const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);

// Update the search index every time a blog post is written.
exports.onUserCreated = functions.firestore.document('organisations/40R0LMA6ALZgF7KjHJMc/employees/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // Get the note document
    const user = snap.data();
  
    // Add an 'objectID' field which Algolia requires
    user.objectID = snap.id;
    console.log(user.objectID)
  
    // Write to the algolia index
    const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);
    return index.saveObject(user);
  });
```

Comment: What error do you get if you add a `catch()` block? `return index.saveObject(user).catch(error => {console.log(error); return null;})`.

Comment: I get the following logs: 'Unreachable hosts - your application id may be incorrect. If the error persists, contact support@algolia.com.', and at the end, I get "Function execution took 2281 ms, finished with status: 'ok' "

Comment: It seems that ALGOLIA_ID is not correct. Did you set the value of this environment variable as explained in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?

Comment: Im not 100% sure. Can I reset everything?

Comment: See my answer which explains how to set the variables and how to inspect what's currently stored in environment config for your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not correctly setting the different environment variables used in this example.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), to get the value of the `algolia.app` environment variable when you do `const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app;` you need to previously set its value as follows:

```
firebase functions:config:set algolia.app="THE_ALGOLIA_ID"
```

Since you need to set several variables, you can set them in one instruction, as follows:

```
firebase functions:config:set algolia.app="THE_ALGOLIA_ID"  algolia.key="THE_ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY" ...
```

---

As explained in the doc, "to inspect what's currently stored in environment config for your project, you can use `firebase functions:config:get`" in the CLI.